# Certificate error when pulling docker images from Azure Container Repository

Tags: azure, docker, acr

We're using Azure DevOps pipelines to build and deploy images to Azure Container Repository. All goes well, but when I try to pull the image I get this error:

```
certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2021-12-12T09:05:46Z is before 2021-12-13T09:35:26Z
```

I can deploy the docker image from my laptop to a Azure Container Repository, and then pulling the image w/o any problems. So it seams the issue is with Azure Container Repository.

Thank you

Comment: You can refer to [Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1468) and  [X509: certificate has expired error](https://forums.docker.com/t/x509-certificate-has-expired-error/68089)

Comment: Did you check the links mentioned in the above comment? Did you get the solution or workaround?

Comment: Thank you for asking, yes I did, but the problem seams to be related to DevOps.

Comment: You can ask this question on [Azure Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem)

Answer (score 0):

It resolved itself after a couple of hours so I assume this was a acr bug.